# How to navigate in awesome-wm between windows just like as between tabs in a browser?

Tags: awesome-wm

Yes I know about Win+tab, Win+j/k, but what I also want is something like tabs in a browser, like Win+N (or Win+Shift+N since Win+N "jumps" to workspaces) or whatever similar), where N e { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 }. So having something like this in this taskbar (hope I name this thing in the top correctly):

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xor512/trashbin/master/awesome_taskbar.png

which can be also shown in "ascii-graphics" like:

```
terminal1 | evince | terminal2 | firefox
```

I want to be to press something like Win+Shift+1 and "jump" to terminal1. Then say press Win+Shift+4 and "jump" to firefox.

So what I want to is not only to be able to switch between workspaces using Win+N, but also switch between programs in a workspace in a similar manner using Win+Shift+N (or another shortcut).

I do not see shortcuts like that by default (maybe I'm blind?). I do know that awful.* documentation is available and it is not that hard to add the commands myself, but I believe there will be a catch as to finding out which window is where in the taskbar (since probably, due to awesome having tile layouts, that may not be exactly the position in the stack, which I can obtain using awful.* API). But maybe I'm coming up with non-existing problems?

Maybe someone can help or this does exist?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've managed to do that (using Mod4-Fn keys):  and awful.client.byidx(relative_idx), but to find a relative index to pass to byidx I first search for a currently focused tab index and subtract focused-tab-index from user provided non-relative-index (n in Shift-Fn) to find it: (if it is positive - it will tell hoiw many windows to the right in the taskbar to "jump" to focus to the correct one, if negative - to the left): https://pastebin.pl/view/22a7b612

Answer (score 0):

My https://github.com/elv13/collision module also handles that (but for the maximized layout only, otherwise it switches to geometric navigation)